# How to change a variable that was called in parameters JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Im working on a project, and in an attempt to shorten the amount of code I wrote a function to call all of them at once. It looks something like this `function Function(peram1) {peram1 = peram1 += 5};` And I call it like so `Function(someVariable)` My issue is that I need to change the variable someVariable from inside the function, even though the value of peram1 is simply just the value of someVariable, but cant directly change it. I call multiple of these functions, so I cant simply just call the actual variable name from within.

```
var someVariable = 5;
var someSeperateVariable = 8;

function Function(peram1) {
    peram1 = peram1 += 5;
};

Function(someVariable);
Function(someSeperateVariable);
console.log(someVariable, someSeperateVariable);
```

Comment: what is the type of your `someVariable`? object, number, string, array?

Comment: Are you able to show an example, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: The variable is an int

Comment: TL;DR - you can't do that. Return the value instead.

Comment: The long and short of it is that Javascript does not have references like PHP or C++.

Comment: @putvande Added one, hope it explains it a little bit better.

Comment: @vlaz is there any way I could directly access the variable without writing 7 seperate functions for each variable I need changed?

Comment: Directly? No. Objects you can modify from inside functions, though. However, I believe you are approaching this incorrectly - I am almost certain that you want to just return the value instead, as that is completely idiomatic JavaScript. Passing a variable, and modifying the original is idiomatic C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object to store variables, pass property name and object to function

```
var obj = {someVariable:5, someSeparateVariable:8};

function fn(prop, obj) {
    obj[prop] += 5;
};

fn("someVariable", obj);
fn("someSeparateVariable", obj);
console.log(obj.someVariable, obj.someSeparateVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider returning a value from Function

```
var peram1 = Function(Peram1);
```

Another option in case peram1 is not an object - is to wrap peram1 with an object:

```
var objContainPeram1 = {    peram1: peram1 }

Function (objContainPeram1) {
     objContainPeram1.peram1 = objContainPeram1.peram1 + 5  
}
```

Comment: Would that require me to make an object containing the variables?

Comment: Yes, See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to wrap your code in a function to create a closure:

```
function closure() {

    var someVariable = 5;
    var someSeperateVariable = 8;

    function foo() {
        someVariable += 5;
    };

    console.log(someVariable)
    foo()
    console.log(someVariable)

}

closure()
```